# Self Location Manager Delegate error in Xcode 6

Tags: ios8, xcode6, cllocationmanager, locationmanager, compass

I'm using code from:
http://www.veasoftware.com/tutorials/2014/6/17/xcode-5-tutorial-ios-7-simple-compass-app
In Xcode 6 I get the error below. The app still runs, but this error is really annoying me.

```
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
//Assigning to 'id<CLLocationManagerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'ViewController *const __strong'
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you forgot to comply with the Core Location Delegate protocol by adding `<CLLocationManagerDelegate>` after `@interface` in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.locationManager.delegate = (id)self;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1)Make your class import the below:

```
#import<CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

2) Make you class adopt the protocol:

```
interface YourClassName : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

3) In Last option to suppress it by doing:

```
self.locationManager.delegate = (id)self;
```

The warning should be gone now.