# IOS CLLocation manager returning zero speed

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

Hi I want to calculate speed within my camera view in XCODE8.  The code does not generate error but my speed is returning zero.  So I searched the link below :[Self Location Manager Delegate error in Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078133/self-location-manager-delegate-error-in-xcode-6).  My code has two interface files, one for CvVideoCamera and one for ClLocationManager. I never had two interface files in my project, so I am not sure I am doing everything correctly. My code is below, Can you please tell me if something is wrong in my code architecture that causing me to get zero speed.

```
viewcontroller.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CvVideoCameraDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) CvVideoCamera* videoCamera;
…
@end
@interface LocationController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic)  CLLocationManager*locationManager;
@end

viewcontroller.m
#import "ViewController.h"
 int speed;
@interface LocationController() {

}

@end
@implementation LocationController
@synthesize locationManager;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
self.locationManager.delegate = (id)self;

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    CLLocation *loc = locations.lastObject;
     loc = locations.lastObject;
    speed = loc.speed * 2.236;

}

@end
@interface ViewController (){
….
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize imageView;

@synthesize videoCamera
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
self.videoCamera.delegate = self;
(void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)image {  
 NSLog(@"speed: %.d”, speed)}
```

Comment: Do you request `whenInUseAuthorization` in order to get permission to use location services?   It would appear not

Comment: I inserted whenInUseAuthorization but still speed is zero    info.plist file change
Privacy - Location Always Usage Description
Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description  - (void)viewDidLoad
 i added in viewDidLoad the following:
    
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
   
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
          [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

Comment: You also need to set location accuracy to `best` to get the GPS powered on